# how can i send http post request from localhost:5000 to localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, localhost

I'm trying to send a http post request from application running on localhost:5000 to my server at localhost:3000

this angular script is running on localhost:5000

```
    var data = {name:"john", description:"100"};
    var url = 'localhost:3000/razor';

    $http.post(url, data).then(function(response){
      if(response.data){
        console.log("success");
      } else {
        console.log("failure");
      }
    });
```

localhost:3000 is not receiving any POST request. What should I do? 
Error in console -

```
Error: A network error occurred.
rg/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js:107:276
p@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js:102:434
n/b<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js:100:207
h/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js:133:460
$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js:147:309
$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js:144:412
$evalAsync/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js:147:398
f@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js:47:146
kg/k.defer/c<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js:50:68
 Possibly unhandled rejection: {}
```

Comment: you're most likely have an error in the console about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). You need to configure the server on `localhost:5000` to support CORS. What kind of server do you run?

Comment: localhost:5000 is Firebase server
localhost:3000 is nodejs server with mongodb

Comment: Can you tell us what your developer console (IE/FF/Chrome) looks like when you make the post. There should be information listed under the network tab.

Comment: adding error in the question

Comment: Are you using angular 2/4 or angularjs?

Comment: using angularjs

Comment: put http:// in front http://localhost:3000/razor

Comment: It works! thanks @Milad

Answer (score 2):

Without `http` in front of the url, the url becomes relative to the current url which is 'http://localhost:5000', so the url that you're posting to becomes 'http://localhost:5000/localhost:3000/razor', but when you add `http` in front of the url, it becomes `absolute` url .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add http in front of url path to make it absolute URL
Try replacing this once

var url = 'http://localhost:3000/razor';

Thanks